# How to set dropdown arrow in spinner with underline from image

Tags: android

1. List item

[image]

my code is in the style

this is inside the style.xml

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme">
        <item name="android:background" >@drawable/bg_spinner</item>
    </style>
```

bg_spinner.xml

```
<item>

    <layer-list>

        <item >
            <bitmap android:gravity="bottom" android:src="@drawable/under_line" />
        </item>

        <item android:right="5dp">
            <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@drawable/dropdown" />

        </item>

    </layer-list>

</item>
```

```
<Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="Sex"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerSex" />
```

date,month and year are in full width,and background image also less width, but when it comes sex its not showing full width.
i need the under line in sex full width, please do the needfull

Comment: Post your xml for the spinner

Comment: <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="Sex"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerSex" />

Comment: Edit your question with it. Cannot read if you add it in the comment section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw line by xml code. like below

```
    <item >

    <layer-list>

        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <!-- background color of box -->
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:left="-2dp"
            android:right="-2dp"
            android:top="-2dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#323232" />
                <!-- color of stroke -->
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:right="5dp">
            <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@drawable/downlarrow" />

        </item>

    </layer-list>

   </item>
```

output looks something like this
[image]

Comment: remove the bitmap tag it'll work fine for edittext also

Comment: if text is of two lines, it get overlapped by bottomline.

Answer (score 0):

replace your xml code with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <!-- Draw a 2dp width border around shape -->
        <stroke
            android:color="#000000"
            android:width="2dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- Overlap the left, top and right border using background color  -->
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Full XML Code is:**

Keep below code in your drawable directory. File name can be like this: "bg_spinner.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <!-- background color of box -->
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:left="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:top="-2dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#323232" />
                <!-- color of stroke -->
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:right="5dp">
            <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@mipmap/arrow_down" />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selector>
```

In above code change bitmap src to your arrow image from drawable or mipmap directory. You can take nice arrow from "File -> New -> Vector Asset"

In your style.xml file keep below code:

```
<style name="SpinnerLineTheme" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_spinner</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

And call the theme from spinner like below:

```
 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
     style="@style/SpinnerLineTheme"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
     android:dropDownWidth="300dp"
     android:dropDownVerticalOffset="60dp"
     android:gravity="start"
     android:paddingEnd="30dp"
     android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

PS: Inspired by @Jayanth answer, as edit request queue is full.